# Alternatives to ORA_ROWSCN in norowdependencies tables

Tags: oracle

I have a table that contains over 33 million rows and it is a norowdependencies table in oracle, and I have to fetch some data using ora_rowscn, which takes a long time (over 6 hours). I don't know if I have another solution than ORA_ROWSCN in Oracle that is specified for norowdependencies tables.

**UPDATE:**

i have a table in sql server that saves the rows that inserted/updated in the oracle table and it must be filled everyday, and since my oracle table have no datetime reference column, i copied all rows then i fixed the max ora_rowscn as a reference and every day i: `select * from my_oracle_table where ora_rowscn > my_fixed_value` and after the insert i: `select max(ora_rowscn) from my_oracle_table` and i use it as a reference for the select of the next day.

Comment: `ORA_ROWSCN` is not accurate, particularly in a `NOROWDEPENDENCIES` ( the default ) table where SCNs are stored in ITL slots at the block level, not the row level. You need to use an alternate methodology for your development. Oracle did not intend SCN's to be used in this way. They are meant for DBAs and are used primarily for recovery and flashback purposes.

Comment: The best solution is to work with the table owner to add a date column. If that absolutely cannot be done, another option is to have them add a trigger that populates a log table with the primary key values of rows inserted or updated, and you can use that log table to drive your incremental extract. But either way you are going to need the table owner to get involved and make some DDL changes.